# VBA - click button in website (HTML button issues)

Tags: html, vba

```html
<button type="button" class="button_primary" id="exportTable"><span>Export</span></button>
```

Hello I am trying to export data into a csv file from my bank website. The website has a button to export the data for me and I am simply trying to click the button. The first button click that I have clicks on the export icon on the page and opens up the option to export but there is then another export button that I cannot seem to get to work. I included the html code and my VBA code. Any  thought of the second segment with Id "exportTable"?

```
Dim ie As Object

Dim html As HTMLDocument

Dim htmlel As IHTMLElement

Dim htmlin As HTMLInputElement

Dim htmlbut As HTMLButtonElement

ie.navigate "website"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Application.StatusBar = "Loading Webpage ..."

DoEvents

Loop

Set htmlbut = ie.document.getElementById("exportTransactions")

htmlbut.Click

Set htmlbut = ie.document.getElementById("exportTable")

htmlbut.Click
```

Comment: Are both buttons promptly available, or `id=exportTable` will be script-created after clicking `id=exportTransactions`? The latter being the case, you'd have to put a wait similar to the "webpage loading" wait, and check whether all elements you need are fully loaded and rendered in the page.

Comment: @Nick Thalken what error do you get? What does wrong when you run the code. "I cannot seem to get to work" is not helpful for us to help you.

Comment: quick way to test if your code will work at all: insert "stop" after the first "click" line. run the code. when it stops, wait a few seconds, then press F8 to single-step, or press F5 to continue without pause (also check the IE instance that gets created)

Comment: Do you even manage to reach that second button ? Ensure it is not embedded in a frame, iframe or form. In that case, you should first select that form/frame/iframe and use the GetElementById from there.

Comment: With my code now the button simply isn't being clicked. It does nothing. No error

Comment: I got it to work using a wait command. Thank you VBobCat and jsotola

Comment: Normally button have a "onclick" or "href" attribute. You could try the "FireEvent" too but few chances it works. If you can provide the url of the website in question I can give it a look.